# how to hide an Angular component based on a condition (specific environment)

Tags: angular, triggers, path, routes

I have a function that checks what my environment is, and a finds the correct config.json file depending on the environment. I use a switch statement.

I need a component to load on the homepage, showing the name of the environment. I created this component and put its name in angle brackets in my home component, and my message with the environment information now appears when the home component is loaded. I now need to figure out how to hide this component if it's in one 
particular environment.

```
this is my home component html file:

<app-show-environment></app-show-environment>
<div class="home-page text-center">
  <div class="home-inner">
    <h1 class="display-2 mb-5" translate>DASHBOARD</h1>
<!--    <router-outlet></router-outlet>-->
  </div>
</div>
```

this is my showEnvironment componenet:

```
<h1>
  You are now in the {{currentEnv}} environment.
</h1>
```

this is my showEnvironment ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {environment} from "../../../environments/environment";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-show-environment',
  templateUrl: './show-environment.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./show-environment.component.scss']
})
export class ShowEnvironmentComponent implements OnInit {
  currentEnv: string;

  constructor() {
    this.currentEnv = environment.name;
  }


  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: actually, I misunderstood what is needed. I need the component to be triggered for each environment except one (production). The component will tell the user in which environment he is.

Comment: You might want to edit the actual question instead of making an update in the comments. Also posting some code samples helps.

Comment: thanks samlu for the tips. I'm very new at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `*ngIf` to conditionally render your template. I just used `production` as an example.

```
<h1 *ngIf="currentEnv !== 'production'">
  You are now in the {{currentEnv}} environment.
</h1>
```

https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#conditional-display-with-ngif

Comment: so simple. I should have known this. I've used Angular before, but it was always in a team. Now I'm the only Angular person on the team. I know about ngIf, ngFor etc, but I'm not used to applying the solution to problems...it'll take a while to get used to.